# node/nvm/npm installations : sudo vs. user install leads to trouble?

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, sudo, javascript

The problem appears to be inconsistency with `root` and `user` installed `node (v.19.7.0)`, `nvm (0.39.3)`, and `npm (v. 9.5.0)` and a specific `npm`-installed package called `svg-path-interpolator` on an Ubuntu 22.0.4 system. Should `node`, `nvm` and `npm` all be uninstalled and reinstalled as `user`, or go through each piecemeal - or is it going to work if everything is left as-is? Perhaps I should note that this is just to get one script to run calculations at the user level, i.e. not for a website to handle lots of web traffic etc.

Background: I have naively tried getting javascript code to run [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75638425/node-js-and-javascript-library-script-example-no-output). The specific package is called `svg-path-interpolator`. There are a number of problems with that project, which led me to scrutinize the installation of `node`, `nvm`, and `npm` - even though simple checks with some simple java scripts e.g. from tutorials or the node website work ok. I think it is good that the version of `node` is turning out to be the "right" one, e.g. `19.7.0`.

It appears my approach to install `npm`, `nvm`, and `node` (at least) was also naive. The commands I used, in order (I think), were:

`sudo apt install npm`

`sudo npm install -g svg-path-interpolator`

`sudo npm install svg-path-interpolator --save`

`npm install svg-path-interpolator`(AT SOME POINT)

`sudo apt install node` (PROBABLY)

Note that `npm` was ran first locally, no special permissions. The script I want to run didn't work, so naturally I ran `npm` "globally", and naturally, the script didn't work. The help page says `In  global  mode (ie, with -g or --global appended to the command), it installs the current package context (ie, the current working directory) as a global package.` - and I have read this idea elsewhere - what does that mean, that the CWD is being used somehow?

I also tried the `--save` option. From reading further - especially regarding permissions and working directory - it appears this willy-nilly user vs. admin installation is bad. Some evidence on my system is (excerpts) :

```
ls -ltraF /home/user/package-lock.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2091 Mar  5 11:46 /home/user/package-lock.json
ls -ltraF ~/node_modules/.package-lock.json 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1117 Mar  5 11:46 /home/user/node_modules/.package-lock.json
```

I also see that `svg-path-interpolator` is missing from:

```
/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v19.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/
```

there's also `node_modules` in `/usr/local/lib`, so it is confusing.

One last clue : in trying to get the original task to work, another error is worrisome (but this might be irrelevant) :

```
./svgpi.mjs config.json  balloons.svg  output.json
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir ''] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: ''
}
```

To solve that, I *might* have run the script with `sudo` once to see what would happen, but it seemed not to do anything (I hope).

So perhaps instead of the dreaded complete uninstall and reinstall but-only-as-user, I could leave things be and simply get rid of `package-lock.json` and write it out as `user` somehow by following the guidance in the `npm` or `nvm` man pages/web pages or Stack Exchange posts - which I have been following carefully. I tried to cover the bases but again I have a long post because the specific thing to ask about or do is unclear - apologies.

Comment: `sudo npm install -g svg-path-interpolator` I would never do this specifically, in other words never execute npm with sudo rights for installing an additional user-space script. Additionally, since at this point some files were overwritten with an ownership to root, every other subsequent command can be suspect of running improperly when attempted to run at the normal user level.

Comment: I'm not sure how else it would be installed "globally", which I thought ```-g``` means - in the README here : https://github.com/justinwilaby/svg-path-interpolator#readme ...

Comment: Depends who you ask. Some people don't like 3rd party package managers (like npm and pip) installing files all over the filesystem, outside the users home. Others care less, and if anything goes wrong, blame Ubuntu :D

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to get things moving along:

The whole point is to run a little script installed by `npm` (described in links above). BTW had to run `dos2unix` on that script. Manually did `export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/node_modules/my-favorite-module-package/bin/`. Relevant tech detail : the `.mjs` file had `await fs.mkdir(dir, {recursive: true});`. This produced an `ENOENT error -2` when script is run as instructed - *with* an output file. Because there was a `mkdir` in that construct in the `.mjs`. I *omitted* the output file, and the process completes (apparently, properly). Omitting the output file was not obvious. All (... most of) the things I wrote in this answer were found by using a search engine and picking usually the top hits which usually / preferentially were on Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange - i.e. it's all in here.

I'm leaving the `nvm`,`node`, `npm`, and whatever else (like `java` or `curl`-installed stuff from even long ago) alone - over time, maybe do something with the root-owned `package` things. Not sure why the `PATH` isn't automagically set after all that, but oh well.

Not strictly an answer but a workaround - one might read the Meta S.E. for an idea of how workaround v. answer is treated on Stack Exchange. Spoiler : workarounds can be answers.